# Broadleaf Commerce remove CMS feature

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

Is it possible to remove the CMS feature of Broadleaf Commerce entirely? I have only found some entries in the documentation on how to extend the system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to remove the sections from the admin and then not use it. The tables would still be in the database they would just remain unused.

You can remove the sections in the admin by deleting the entries in `BLC_ADMIN_SECTION`.

Comment: I was afraid about such an answer. So this means the CMS feature can't be removed like a module because it's an integral part of the core distribution?

Comment: Hm but on the other hand the doc says: "The core framework consists of the modules in the following table. It would be exceptionally rare for a Broadleaf Commerce implementation NOT to use all of these core modules". So it seems the CMS part is kind of a module...